# Decorators unexpectedly change constructor behavior in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

Below, I show a simplified example of a more complicated code, but nonetheless, it fully represents the issue that I have encountered.

**Part 1**: this works fine, no issues:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, animal_name = "no name given"):    
        self.set_name(animal_name) 
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self._animal_name
    
    def set_name(self, animal_name):
        self._animal_name = animal_name

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, dog_breed = "no breed", dog_name = "no name given"):
        self._dog_breed = dog_breed
        super().__init__(dog_name)
        
    def get_breed(self):
        print(self._dog_breed)

x = Dog('Greyhound', 'Rich')
```

**Part 2**: after introducing getter & setter decorators, the code stops working:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, animal_name = "no name given"):
        #THE LINE BELOW SEEMS TO CAUSE AN ISSUE
        self.name(animal_name)
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._animal_name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, animal_name):
        self._animal_name = animal_name

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, dog_breed = "no breed", dog_name = "no name given"):
        self._dog_breed = dog_breed
        super().__init__(dog_name)
        
    def get_breed(self):
        print(self._dog_breed)

x = Dog('Greyhound', 'Rich')
```

**Output**: AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute '_animal_name'

When I keep the decorators in Part 2 but change the constructor in the Animal class to:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, animal_name = "no name given"):
        self._animal_name=animal_name
```

It works.

I am just curious why it doesn't work in the example above in **Part 2**?

Comment: Does it work if you use `self.name=animal_name` instead of `self.name(animal_name)`?

Comment: Yes, that solves the issue. So when I use the decorators, I need to treat the getter and setter methods within the class as a property, even in the class constructor: I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

The line

```
self.name(animal_name)
```

can be split in two parts:

```
tmp = self.name
tmp(animal_name)
```

First, `self.name` calls the getter and the result is treated as a function. The getter uses `return self._animal_name` and since the setter has never been called, the respective error occurs.

**Long answer:**

Let's take the following class:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animal_name):
        self.name(animal_name)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._animal_name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, animal_name):
        self._animal_name = animal_name
```

To understand what the line

```
self.name(animal_name)
```

actually does, you first need to understand decorators.

The code

```
@dec
def func(a, b, ...):
    [...]
```

is equivalent to

```
def func_impl(a, b, ...):
    [...]
func = dec(func_impl)
```

(except that you can not call `func_impl` directly). See, for example, [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax) for more information.

This means that you can write the `Animal` class from above without using decorators:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animal_name):
        self.name(animal_name)

    def get_name(self):
        return self._animal_name
    name = property(get_name)

    def set_name(self, animal_name):
        self._animal_name = animal_name
    name = name.setter(set_name)
```

In order to understand this code, you need to understand the builtin `property`, which is a class. See [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) for detailed information.

The line `name = property(get_name)` creates an object of type `property`. When retrieving the value of the property, `get_name` is called.

The line `name = name.setter(set_name)` first calls `name.setter(set_name)`, which creates a copy of the property, and then overwrites `name` with this copy. When assigning a value to the copy, `set_name` is called.

All in all, `name` is an object of type `property` that uses `get_name` as getter and `set_name` as setter.

**How does this help?**

You need to understand this: *`name` is not a function.* It is a property. It is not callable.

The problematic line

```
self.name(animal_name)
```

is actually equivalent to

```
self.get_name()(animal_name)
```

which this explains the error message: The constructor calls the getter, which tries to use `return self._animal_name`. But since the setter has not been called, yet, `self._animal_name` has not been set.